# How can i search in to array for duplicated objects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

i have array like this structure and want push some Non-duplicate objects

```js
[
 {
   applicationNumber: "2",
   id: "8cca5572-7dba-49de-971b-c81f77f221de",
   country: 23,
   totalPrice: 36
 },
 {
   applicationNumber: "3",
   id: "8cca5572-33333-49de-971b-c81f77f221de",
   country: 1,
   totalPrice: 2
 }
]
```

i want to search on this array before push any other object on it to check existing object and after that if is not any existing object, push new object or if existing update that object only. how can i do this thing?

Comment: Do you consider duplicate an exact match, I mean, all the attributes? Or only one of the properties?

Comment: @manuman94 no only check with object id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use an event to run function on every change and after that use loop like below

```
vents.$on('newArr', (newArray) => {
            let i;
            for (i = 0; i < this.exportData.length; i++) {
                let obj = this.exportData[i];
                if (obj.id === newArray.id) {
                    delete this.exportData[i];
                }
            }
            this.exportData.push(newArray);
        });
```

i think it's simple and clear also if anyone think this way not optimize or not good tell me about that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a function called `addToArray` that takes the original array and the new object to add as parameters, inside it find the index of that object of it already exist override it else push it at the end :

```js
let arr = [{
    id: 1,
    country: 45
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    country: 23
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    country: 75
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    country: 39
  }

]

function addToArray(ar, val) {
  let index = ar.findIndex(item => item.id === val.id);
   (index >= 0) ? ar[index] = val:ar.push(val)
}

console.log('before :',arr)

addToArray(arr, {
  id: 2,
  country: 86
})

console.log('after : ',arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ES6 `Array.findIndex()` function. Like so:

```js
let sampleArray = [
 {
   applicationNumber: "2",
   id: "8cca5572-7dba-49de-971b-c81f77f221de",
   country: 23,
   totalPrice: 36
 },
 {
   applicationNumber: "3",
   id: "8cca5572-33333-49de-971b-c81f77f221de",
   country: 1,
   totalPrice: 2,
 }
];

const updateArr = newData =>
{
   const existingIndex = sampleArray.findIndex(obj => obj.id === newData.id);
   if (existingIndex >= 0)
      sampleArray[existingIndex] = { ...sampleArray[existingIndex], ...newData };
   else
      sampleArray.push(newData)
}

const newData = { id: "8cca5572-33333-49de-971b-c81f77f221de", country: 67637674634 }
updateArr(newData);
console.log(sampleArray)
```